# C recursive program to print all prime factors of a given number from the biggest factor to the smallest

Tags: c, recursion, prime-factoring

i'm trying to write a program that print the prime factors of a given number ,**but** i need to print them from the biggest factor to the smallest, for example:
for the input ***180*** the output will be: **5*3*3*2*2**,
any suggestions?  here is what i got for now :

```
#include<stdio.h>


void print_fact(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return;
    int num=2;
    while (n%num != 0)
        num++;
    printf("*%d",num);
    print_fact (n/num);

}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf("please insert a number \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    print_fact(n);
}
```

for this code the output is :

`*2*2*3*3*5`

Comment: Try stepping through the function, line by line, in a debugger. Step into the recursive calls. Then it should be very obvious what the problem is. Also please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Speed gains to be had are 1) extract all the twos first (print them last), and loop from `num=3` with `num+=2;`, and 2) you don't need to try divisors all the way to `n`, only to its square root with `(num*num <= n)`.

Comment: You don't print anything if the user types 1 as the value.  That's not particularly good.  There's also zero and all the negative numbers that could be entered to worry about at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply print the output after the recursive call returns. You need to slightly modify how you display the `*`, which I leave to you.

```
#include<stdio.h>


void print_fact(int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return;
    int num=2;
    while (n%num != 0)
        num++;
     // printf("*%d",num); // remove from here
    print_fact (n/num);
    printf("%d ",num); // put here

}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    printf("please insert a number \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    print_fact(n);
}
```

The output this gives on input `180` is:

```
5 3 3 2 2
```

Aside, there are much more efficient ways of actually *finding* the numbers though.

Comment: That's correct but every time it starts from 2 and it's useless. You should track the value of `num` without re initializing it at every call

Answer (score 1):

It is much faster to find them in the ascending order, mathematically speaking. Much, much faster.

The solution, if you don't want to bother yourself with dynamic arrays, is recursion. Find the lowest prime factor, recurse on the divided out number (`num /= fac`), and *then* print the earlier found factor, which will thus appear *last*.

Answer (score 0):

to change the order in which they are printed, you could put the `printf` statement after the `print_fact` statement. To get rid of thew leading `*`, you would probably want to store the results and display them after computation

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm trying to optimize my algorithm 
this is my code for now:
functions code

```
#include "prime_func.h"


int divisors(int x) /* Function To set the maximum size of the future array,
                       Since there is no way to find the number of primary factors 
                       without decomposing it into factors,
                       we will take the number of total number divisors 
                       (which can not be greater than the number of primary factors) */
{
    int limit = x;
    int numberOfDivisors = 0;

    if (x == 1) return 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < limit; ++i) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            limit = x / i;
            if (limit != i) {
                numberOfDivisors++;
            }
            numberOfDivisors++;
        }
    }

    return numberOfDivisors;
}
void find_fact(int n, int *arr, int size, int i) //func to find the factors and apply them in allocated array
{
    int num = 2;
    if (n < 2) 
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return;
    }
    while (n%num != 0)
        num++;
    arr[i++] = num;
    find_fact(n / num, arr, size, i);


}
void print_fact(int *arr, int size) // func to print the array in reverse
{
    int i = 0;
    int first;
    first = FirstNumToPrint(arr, size);
    for (i = first; i>0; i--)
        printf("%d*", arr[i]);
    printf("%d", arr[0]);
}

int FirstNumToPrint(int *arr, int size) // func to find the first number to print (largest prime factor)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            return i - 1;
}


int first_prime(int num) // for now i'm not using this func
{
    for (int i = 2; i<sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0)
        {
            if (isprime(i));
            return(i);
        }
    }
}
bool isprime(int prime) // for now i'm not using this func
{
    for (int i = 2; i<sqrt(prime); i++)
    {
        if (prime%i == 0)
            return(false);
    }
    return(true);
}
```

main code

```
#include "prime_func.h"

int main()
{
    int n,i=0; // first var for input, seconde for index
    int *arr; // array for saving the factors
    int size;//size of the array
    printf("please insert a number \n");// asking the user for input
    scanf("%d", &n);
    size = divisors(n); //set the max size
    arr = (int *)calloc(size,sizeof(int)); //allocate the array
    if (arr == NULL) // if the allocation failed
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    find_fact(n, arr,size,i);// call the func
    print_fact(arr,size); //print the result
    free(arr); // free memo
}
```

@WillNess @GoodDeeds @mcslane